# why a object correctly construct with deserialize method have a failure test is Myclass ? or as MyClass cast?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I serialize objects of a parent class and derived from it

```
namespace CyXml
{
    [Serializable]
    public class XmlInfo : IFormattable, ISerializable
    {
        public string Mnemonique { get; set; }
....
   }
    [Serializable]
    public class XmlLabel: XmlInfo
    {
        public XmlLabel()
            : base()
        {
        }
....
   }
    [Serializable]
    public class XmlVoyant : XmlInfo
    {
        public XmlVoyant()
            : base()
        {
        }
        ....
   }
    [Serializable]
    public class XmlButton: XmlInfo
    {
        public XmlButton()
            : base()
        {
        }
        ....
   }


}
```

when the déssérialisation of an ArrayList as the Type of the object is correct, the test is not working .

```
ArrayList XmlInfos = new ArrayList ();
public void ReadXmllInfo(int vue)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader =
      new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayList),
        new Type[]{
            typeof(CyXml.XmlInfo),
            typeof(CyXml.XmlLabel),
            typeof(CyXml.XmlVoyant),
            typeof(CyXml.XmlButton)});

    string xml = String.Format(@"C:\XML\Outil{0}.xml", vue);
    System.IO.StreamReader file = null;
    try
    {
        file = new System.IO.StreamReader(xml);

        XmlInfos = (ArrayList)reader.Deserialize(file); 

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (file != null)
            file.Close();
    }
    int TabIndex=this.Controls.Count;

    foreach(var elmt in XmlInfos)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(elmt.GetType().ToString());
        Type serie=elmt.GetType();
        XmlInfo elmt1 = new XmlInfo();
        Type serie1 = elmt1.GetType();
        elmt1 = (XmlInfo)elmt;

        if (elmt is XmlInfo )
        {
        ....
        }
        else if (elmt is XmlLabel)
        {
        ....
        }
        else if (elmt is XmlVoyant)
        {
        ....
        }
        else if (elmt is XmlButton)
        {
        ....
        }
    }

}
```

it is impossible for me to assign the objects from the déssérialisation an object of the parent class.

```
elmt1 = (XmlInfo)elmt;
```

System.InvalidCastException exception was unhandled by user code Message = [A] CyXml.XmlInfo can not be converted to [B] CyXml.XmlInfo . Type A comes from ' IHMTest , Version = 1.0.0.0 , Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' in the context 'Default' in the location 'C: \ TwinCAT \ TcApplication \ Plugins \ IHMTest.dll ' . Type B comes from ' IHMTest , Version = 1.0.0.0 , Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null' in the context ' LoadFrom ' in the location 'C: \ TwinCAT \ Plugins \ IHMTest.dll ' . Source = IHMTest

this code works correctly in a program but does not work in a dll

someone has an idea ?

Cordially

Comment: `n'a pas été gérée par le code utilisateur` bla bla bla. You can at least use google translate to post the error message in English.

Comment: I editted your exception into English so it is readable.  Your title could also be a better written such as :  "XmlSerializer.Serialize object will not Deserialize back to the original object type"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to convert an implementation of `XmlInfo` declared in one DLL to an instance of a *different* implementation of `XmlInfo` declared in a different DLL.

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say what the best way to fix this is. But it is very likely that you have for some reason copy/pasted the implementation from one DLL to another, possibly through actually compiling the same .cs file in both DLLs, resulting in the two different types being declared.

In general, the right way to fix this will be to only declare the type in one place, and have all code that depends on the type reference the *one* DLL where it is declared.

Comment: By hiding the name of the directory that contains information that is private and personal, I see your that there were two dll same in my project (copy by a post-build). it is actually this that is the cause of my troubles!

Thank you very much